# latest gganimate: How to have a fixed plot in the background?

Tags: r, gganimate

In the latest version of gganimate by https://github.com/thomasp85 I would like to choose which parts of the plot I can keep static throughout the animation and which will be animated. In the previous version of gganimate you could specify the *frame* in the *aes* of ggplot. Thus you could create a base plot that would be static and plot the animated plot over this. How can similar be achieved in the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been addressed in an issue for `gganimate` on GitHub: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/94

Basically you specify the the layers that are meant to be static with a separate data frame from the one you initially passed to `ggplot`. The example in the GitHub ticket I referred to is

```
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(dat = data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10), aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x2 = 1:10, y = 1:10),
            aes(x = x2, y = y, group = 1)) +
  transition_time(x)
animate(last_plot(), nframes = 50)
```

Here the line is held static, while the point is moving.