# Wiggling lines when animating ggplot choropleth with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, gganimate

I have a problem when using `gganimate` to animate a choropleth map made with `ggplot2`.

A selection of my data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zSq7HzqVTaMJn8_JjFT02kXkWfLk4L5v) and the code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

part_data <- readRDS(file = "part_data.Rds")

p <- part_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = confirmed), color = "grey70", size = 0.05) +
  coord_map() +
  scale_fill_distiller(trans = "log10", direction = 1, palette = "YlOrRd", na.value = "white") + 
  transition_time(time = date)

animate(p,
        fps = 3, 
        duration = 5,
        renderer = gifski_renderer("countyevolution.gif"),
        width = 1200, height = 750, res = 100)
```

which yields this GIF:
[image: GIF]

Perhaps it's difficult to see but if you look closely you'll see that the borders between the counties are wiggling. This does not happen when I use `transition_manual` without transitions between the dates, so it must come from these transitions. But why?

Is it possible to somehow tell `gganimate` to keep the borders the same and only render the `fill` for each frame? Or can I somehow else make the border less obvious? I tried decreasing the `size`, but that does not seem to make a difference. Also, the borders seem a bit jagged.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to em recently: animated plots that contain maps or other static elements become wiggly or blink. I realized the wiggle happens because `gganimate` is also animating the map lines in each step of the animation. This explains why using other transition modes or removing transition animations solve the blinking.

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921858/4467386), to exclude a ggplot layer from being animated you need to add a `data` argument. This way, the map or plot in the background will remain static, and the rest of the plot will animate.